# How to use tailwind css code in simple html file which is used in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I used tailwind css code in react mostly in a css file where i used @apply. Now i want to switch to simple html with tailwind cdn so how can i do that?

IT LOOKS LIKE THIS

[React code with tailwind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpFSu.png)

And this is html file codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-herschel-ypb3de?file=/index.html

and it looks like this

[TAILWIND WITH html design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhbGF.png)

can someone help me with this?

Comment: `@apply` is PostCss syntax. So if you want to use apply, you need to install tailwind without cdn. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Comment: @Amini i Can't use node.js in it. Because i am using php file

Comment: Do you have any other solution please

Comment: You need to install node js even if you're developing a backend app. (If you needed front-end packages)

Comment: @Amini how can i do it? with php. Can you please share a demo and can tell me

Answer (score 0):

mustryy,

Set up the tailwindcss for your HTML codebase, and copy the complete code of your react project into your HTML page, But be careful that don't copy the component code from responding to HTML.

Read this documentation for tailwindcss set up in HTML - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Comment: But i have custom tailwind css which isn't working. Can you check this https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-herschel-ypb3de?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically adding CDN and its works. but it's not working so install [postcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss)  through try

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      class="min-h-full flex items-center justify-center py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8"
    >
      <div class="max-w-md w-full space-y-8">
        <div>
          <img
            class="mx-auto h-12 w-auto"
            src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=600"
            alt="Workflow"
          />
          <h2
            class="mt-6 text-center text-3xl tracking-tight font-bold text-gray-900"
          >
            Sign in to your account
          </h2>
          <p class="mt-2 text-center text-sm text-gray-600">
            Or
            <a
              href="#"
              class="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500"
            >
              start your 14-day free trial
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <form class="mt-8 space-y-6" action="#" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="remember" value="true" />
          <div class="rounded-md shadow-sm -space-y-px">
            <div>
              <label for="email-address" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
              <input
                id="email-address"
                name="email"
                type="email"
                autocomplete="email"
                required
                class="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-t-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Email address"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
              <input
                id="password"
                name="password"
                type="password"
                autocomplete="current-password"
                required
                class="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-b-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Password"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
            <div class="flex items-center">
              <input
                id="remember-me"
                name="remember-me"
                type="checkbox"
                class="h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500 border-gray-300 rounded"
              />
              <label for="remember-me" class="ml-2 block text-sm text-gray-900">
                Remember me
              </label>
            </div>

            <div class="text-sm">
              <a
                href="#"
                class="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500"
              >
                Forgot your password?
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            <button
              type="submit"
              class="group relative w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
            >
              <span class="absolute left-0 inset-y-0 flex items-center pl-3">
                <!-- Heroicon name: solid/lock-closed -->
                <svg
                  class="h-5 w-5 text-indigo-500 group-hover:text-indigo-400"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                >
                  <path
                    fill-rule="evenodd"
                    d="M5 9V7a5 5 0 0110 0v2a2 2 0 012 2v5a2 2 0 01-2 2H5a2 2 0 01-2-2v-5a2 2 0 012-2zm8-2v2H7V7a3 3 0 016 0z"
                    clip-rule="evenodd"
                  />
                </svg>
              </span>
              Sign in
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

checkout [Documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)